# Change single page url with functions.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 different pages:

mysite.com/pageparent
mysite.com/pagechild

I want to change the url to: mysite.com/pageparent/pagechild

They need to be pages not posts, I can't use categories.

If I try to change the url in the page edit it changes it to mysite.com/pageparent-pagechild

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Parent Page](https://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/page-options/#parent-page) on page edit